# How to return the first 2 objects of an array of 4 objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setinterval, splice

I want to return the first 2 objects of an array of 4 objects then add the other two objects with 5 seconds in between.

note: I am reversing the copied array `revEvents`  with `reverse()` as items are in descending order by date/time, the most recent item goes on top.

My current issue is the first two objects are displayed ok, then after 5 seconds, it loads only the third object and it stops.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   let ms = 3000
   let i = 0
   let displayedEvents = [...props].splice(i, 2)
   setEventsProps(displayedEvents.reverse())
   const interval = setInterval(() => {
     if (++i <= props.length) {
       displayedEvents = props.splice(0, i + 2)
       setEventsProps(displayedEvents.reverse())
      }
    }, ms)
    return () => { clearInterval(interval) }
    }, [])

 //JSX as below
 displayedEvents.map(event () => ...etc
```

Comment: Have you tried removing setInterval and replace it with a setTimeout? (including clearTimeout) Then you dont need the return () => {clearInterval(interval)}

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share an improved solution.

```js
   useEffect(() => {
        const ms = 5000
        let i = 2
        const displayedEvents: IEventsProps = props.slice(0, 2)
        setEventsProps(displayedEvents.reverse())
        let interval: NodeJS.Timeout = setInterval((): void => {
            if (i < props.length) {
                displayedEvents.push(props[i])
                setEventsProps(displayedEvents.reverse())
                i += 1
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval)
                interval = null
            }
        }, ms)
        return () => { if (interval) { clearInterval(interval) } }
    }, [])
```

This avoids making unnecessary new arrays by mutating the same array, and also clears the interval when the work is done, so it doesn't run forever.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue, instead of using the `splice()` function I needed to use the `slice()` function instead.

The code remains the same, added typescript for anyone who find this.

```
   useEffect(() => {
        let ms: number = 5000
        let i: number = 0
        let displayedEvents: IEventsProps = [...props].slice(i, 2)
        setEventsProps(displayedEvents.reverse())
            const interval: NodeJS.Timeout = setInterval((): void => {
                if (++i <= props.length) {
                    displayedEvents = props.slice(0, i + 2)
                    setEventsProps(displayedEvents.reverse())
                }
            }, ms)
        return () => { clearInterval(interval) }
    }, [])
```

Comment: No need to copy your array via `[...props]`, `slice` already makes a new array.

Comment: This code will run the interval _forever_ (until the component unmounts). You should call `clearInterval` after you've gotten through all of the props. You condition is also wrong and runs 2 extra times, should be `if (++i <= props.length - 2)`